# Looping through multiple collection of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, linq

I have a lot of data as response not parsed and also, so you can see what is in the response. But I want all the scores from the table results, the query filters on `actorId`, `categoryId`, what gets all the data of all subjects from that specific `actorId`.

How can I show all the scores filtered by `actorId` and `categoryId`. I can see that the scores is listed in the results array.

Parsed data response from the localhost of my:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Word",
    "tests": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Test  1",
        "name": "Test 1",
        "description": "This is the description of the first Test",
        "totalPoints": 2,
        "duration": 30,
        "level": 1,
        "subjectId": 1,
        "questions": [],
        "paragraphs": [],
        "results": [
          {
            "id": 22,
            "score": 100,
            "timeElapsed": 5,
            "actorId": 13,
            "actor": null,
            "testId": 1,
            "resultQuestions": [],
            "resultSliders": []
          }
        ],
        "sliders": [],
        "pausedTests": []
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "new test",
        "name": "new test",
        "description": "asdf",
        "totalPoints": 0,
        "duration": 9,
        "level": 3,
        "subjectId": 1,
        "questions": [],
        "paragraphs": [],
        "results": [
          {
            "id": 19,
            "score": 0,
            "timeElapsed": 4,
            "actorId": 13,
            "actor": null,
            "testId": 5,
            "resultQuestions": [],
            "resultSliders": []
          }
        ],
        "sliders": [],
        "pausedTests": []
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "title": "test",
        "name": "test-1",
        "description": "Dit is een test",
        "totalPoints": 2,
        "duration": 1,
        "level": 1,
        "subjectId": 1,
        "questions": [],
        "paragraphs": [],
        "results": [],
        "sliders": [],
        "pausedTests": []
      }
    ],
    "schools": [],
    "categoryId": 1,
    "category": null
  }
]
```

Data that comes back if you console.log the response of the API from the `console.log(response)`:

```
The function is called [{"id":1,"name":"Word","tests":[{"id":1,"title":"Test  1","name":"Test 1","description":"This is the description of the first Test","totalPoints":2,"duration":30,"level":1,"subjectId":1,"questions":[],"paragraphs":[],"results":[{"id":22,"score":100.0,"timeElapsed":5,"actorId":13,"actor":null,"testId":1,"resultQuestions":[],"resultSliders":[]}],"sliders":[],"pausedTests":[]},{"id":5,"title":"new test","name":"new test","description":"asdf","totalPoints":0,"duration":9,"level":3,"subjectId":1,"questions":[],"paragraphs":[],"results":[{"id":19,"score":0.0,"timeElapsed":4,"actorId":13,"actor":null,"testId":5,"resultQuestions":[],"resultSliders":[]}],"sliders":[],"pausedTests":[]},{"id":8,"title":"test","name":"test-1","description":"Dit is een test","totalPoints":2,"duration":1,"level":1,"subjectId":1,"questions":[],"paragraphs":[],"results":[],"sliders":[],"pausedTests":[]}],"schools":[],"categoryId":1,"category":null},{"id":2,"name":"PowerPoint","tests":[{"id":2,"title":"Test  2","name":"Test 1","description":"This is the description of the first Test","totalPoints":2,"duration":30,"level":2,"subjectId":2,"questions":[],"paragraphs":[],"results":[],"sliders":[],"pausedTests":[]},{"id":3,"title":"De titel der titelen","name":"Deze test heet programmeren voor gevorderden","description":"Deze test gaat over hoe leraren ict moet leren begrijpen.","totalPoints":25,"duration":30,"level":3,"subjectId":2,"questions":[],"paragraphs":[],"results":[{"id":20,"score":44.0,"timeElapsed":50,"actorId":13,"actor":null,"testId":3,"resultQuestions":[],"resultSliders":[]}],"sliders":[],"pausedTests":[]}],"schools":[],"categoryId":1,"category":null},{"id":3,"name":"Excel","tests":[],"schools":[],"categoryId":1,"category":null},{"id":7,"name":"Test","tests":[],"schools":[],"categoryId":1,"category":null}]
```

I tried for myself if I could get the score's back from the results array table.

```
function showAllSubjectsScores(response) {
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(response);

console.log('The function is called', parsedData[results][0].score)
    
}
```

This is how the API call is made for the response of all the data:

```
// Global var's
var categoryId = 1;
var actorId = 13; // This is my actorId
var websiteUrl = localStorage.getItem('url');

function getSubjectsByActorid() {
    var xHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xHttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {

            var response = xHttp.response;
            if (xHttp.status == 200) {
                console.log('ANTWOORD IS TERUG VAN DE SERVER')

                showAllSubjectsScores(response);

            } else {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(xHttp.status);

            }
        }
    };

    xHttp.onerror = function () {
        console.log(xHttp.statusText);
    };

    xHttp.open("GET", websiteUrl + "/api/Subjects/" + categoryId + "/" + actorId, true);

    xHttp.send();
    console.log('AANVRAAG IS VERZONDEN')
}
function showAllSubjectsScores(response) {
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(response);

    console.log('The function is called', response)
    
}
getSubjectsByActorid();
```

This is how the API query is built:

```
// GET: api/Subjects
        [HttpGet("/api/Subjects/{categoryId}/{actorId}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<Subject>>> GetSubjectResults(int categoryId, int actorId)
        {
        var subjectResults = _context.Subjects
       .Where(i => i.CategoryId == categoryId)
       .Include(t => t.Tests)
       .ThenInclude(r => r.Results.Where(a => a.ActorId == actorId))
        .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

            if (subjectResults == null)
            {
                return StatusCode(204);
            }

            return await subjectResults;
        }
```

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: As i said i have a lot of data and from the response i want to have all the scores back, this is sorted by actorid and categoryid, the question is how can i show all the scores per actorid filtered on categorieid, the things i tried weren't working

Comment: Looks like you're accessing your object wrong.`parsedData[results][0].score` --> `parsedData[0].tests[0].results[0].score`

Comment: I think object/map/array design is crucial for ones application and how you access relative information in moments. Overall no comment on problem seems comment above solves it. I would suggest not fearing multiple dictionaries to make referencing much faster!

Comment: @kemicofaghost it works thnx, but how can i loop through a.l the scores of the response

Comment: Thnx for the help this works, parsedData[0].tests[0].results[0].score. Only i want to show all the tetscore of the json response, how do i do that

Answer (score 0):

Using the Newtonsoft library to parse the JSON and some typed classes to tease the JSON into something workable, you can do the following.

The SelectMany operator unrolls a list into items into a parent list. Since the JSON has many inner list, this is one way to roll this up.

Note that I removed all the extraneous JSON properties from your example, not related to your question, to keep the answer short and concise, but you can add them to your final implementation.

Here is the result:

```
CategoryId: 1, ActorId: 13, Score: 100.0
CategoryId: 1, ActorId: 13, Score: 0.0
```

Here is the working code example:

```
void Main()
{
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Category>>(GetData());

    var result = data
        .GroupBy(x => x.CategoryId)
        .SelectMany(grp => grp.Select(
            g => g.Tests.SelectMany(
                t => t.Results).Select(
                    t => new {CategoryId = grp.Key, t.ActorId, t.Score})))
        .SelectMany(grp => grp);
    
    foreach (var x in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"CategoryId: {x.CategoryId}, ActorId: {x.ActorId}, Score: {x.Score}");
    }
}

public static string GetData()
{
    return @"
        [
            {
                ""tests"":
                [
                    {
                        ""results"":
                        [
                            {
                                ""score"": 100.0,
                                ""actorId"": 13
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        ""results"":
                        [
                            {
                                ""score"": 0.0,
                                ""actorId"": 13
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                ""categoryId"": 1
            }
        ]"; 
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public IEnumerable<Result> Results  { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public int ActorId { get; set; }
    public decimal Score { get; set; }
}
```